# Chrome debugger shows error in wrong version of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-devtools

I have simple web calculator and JSON printer. Calculator works fine, but I'm getting error "Unexpected token ] in JSON" when I'm trying to print data from JSON file. The problem is that I've already deleted this "]", but after refreshing site or reseting http-server I'm still getting this error, and my JSON looks exactly the same way it was earlier. What's the problem here?

my JS:

```
'use strict';
var showData = (function() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = "games.json";

return {
  gamesData: function() {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            showGames(myArr);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
};
})();

function showGames(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<p>Title: ' + arr[i].title + '</p>' + '<p>Producer: ' + arr[i].producer + '</p>' + '<p>Release date: ' + arr[i].release + '</p>' + '<p>Genre: ' + arr[i].genre + '</p>';
    }
    document.getElementById("games-data").innerHTML = out;
  }
```

my JSON:

```
[
{

"title" : "Diablo",
"producer" : "Blizzard",
"release" : 1996,
"genre" : "hack'n'slash"
 },

   {
     "title" : "Diablo 2",
     "producer" : "Blizzard",
     "release" : 2000,
     "genre" : "hack'n'slash"
   },

   {
     "title" : "Diablo 3",
     "producer" : "Blizzard",
     "release" : 2012,
     "genre" : "hack'n'slash"
   },

   {
     "title" : "Overwatch",
     "producer" : "Blizzard",
     "release" : 2016,
     "genre" : "FPS"
   },

   {
     "title" : "Heroes of the Storm",
     "producer" : "Blizzard",
     "release" : 2015,
     "genre" : "MOBA"
   },

   {
     "title" : "FIFA 16",
     "producer" : "EA Sports",
     "release" : 2015,
     "genre" : "Sport"
   },

   {
     "title" : "Team Fortress 2",
     "producer" : "Valve",
     "release" : 2007,
     "genre" : "FPS"
   }
 ]
```

I'm trying to call showData.gamesData() as js onlick method, but I'm getting this json error. When I click link to the error it red-underlines the coma after "Diablo 2" with error I've already written in this topic.

Comment: have you checked that your json is valid? [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: can you add your code and the error point to the line that is causing the issue?

Comment: ok, i don't know completely why, but it started, to work. I haven't changed anything in code. Just restarted server few more times, and it works.

Comment: Remember, caches suck. Always make sure with oddities like this that you are clearing caches on the *client* and any *server* caches that may exist.